# How to have standardize="None" on Tensorflow TextVectorization

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, word2vec

This is probably a *really* simple problem but I cannot figure it out. I am using Tensorflow's TextVectorization feature but I do not want any standardization on my text. Here are the packaged I am importing:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras import Input
from tensorflow.data import Dataset
```

And here is what my actual code looks like:

```
vectorize_layer = TextVectorization(max_tokens=10000, standardize="None", split='`', output_mode='int', output_sequence_length=3)
```

Here is the error I am getting (with this specific case as "None"):

```
ValueError: The standardize argument of layer TextVectorization received an invalid value None. Allowed values are: `None`, a `Callable`, or one of the following values: lower_and_strip_punctuation.
```

I have tried standardized="None", 'None', "none", 'none', None and none, and nothing has worked. I looked at the documentation and blog posts, but I have no idea what I am doing wrong... Any thoughts

Comment: I tried passing `None` and it works.

Comment: How interesting. Just None with no quotation marks?

Comment: try ```None``` without any quotation marks (single or double quotation). it may solve the problem.

Comment: It look like a bug here. If you pass `standardize=None` it is working.Please raise bug [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues).One more suggestion instead of `from tensorflow.keras.layers.experimental.preprocessing import TextVectorization` you can try as `from tensorflow.keras.layers import TextVectorization`.Thanks!